# How come Jason can stay safe when Professor X attacked mutants in X2?

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-2

In *X2: X Men United*, Professor X and Jason are in the cerebro where Jason tries to make him kill all the mutants. When Professor does this, all mutants starts to scream and squirm, but Jason doesn't.

Why does Jason, who is a mutant and connected with Professor's mind, stay safe from this?

Comment: Speculation based on vague memories: Cerebro helps amplify the mind power of Professor X outward to other mutants.  It's possible that, since Magneto helped build it, it's got some clever shielding to prevent the amplified signal back into itself.

Comment: ohh.... that seems plausible.

Comment: There's no indication that mutants **inside** Cerebro would be affected at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are three possible answer (one of which was already addressed in the comments.

1. Cerebro is shielded, and any mutant inside Cerebro is safe from Charles' attack.
2. Jason is a mutant with psychic powers, much like Charles. Not only that but he is (artificially) stronger than Charles, as he forces him to execute the attack. If Jason is capable of this, it's possible that he is capable of withstanding Charles' attack.
3. Similar to point 2, Jason may be able to resist Charles' attack because of something that made him resilient during the process that made him the (freaky) psychic that he is in the movie. Much of Jason's power (and creepiness) comes from the fact that his own father experimented on him to turn him into a weapon. Who knows what they did to him.

**Edit** From the comments below, and the phrasing of the question, I thought of a 4th option.

> When Professor does this, all mutants starts to scream and squirm, but Jason doesn't.

Jason is not normal, even by mutant standards. He does not talk, he does not even seem "human" (behaviorally). He is a psychic weapon more than anything else.

4. Just because Jason wasn't seen screaming, does not mean he doesn't experience pain.

Maybe Jason did experience the pain, but he simply didn't show it externally as he is incapable of "normal" behavior. There is also no proof that Jason is even still capable of experiencing pain in general. The extent of the experiments that have been done with Jason could very well have rendered him either incapable of feeling pain, or given him the ability to ignore pain as an overriding emotional response. He was focused on forcing Charles, after all. And he possibly does not have a will to live, and therefore doesn't panic at the thought of dying.

Comment: Cerebro empowers Charles so that he can use psychic powers on any human or mutant across the world. I don't think Jason could have withstood that. Most likely he controlled the professor into sparing him or anyone within the Cerebro can not be targeted by it.

Comment: @LiquidSame: As I understand it, Cerebro amplifies the _range_ at which Charles can connect to humans. Similarly, a powered wifi antenna extends the range of the network, but not its network speed. Considering how long Charles fought tooth and nail (psychically) with Jason, that means that Jason did not lose the fight and resisted Charles' counterattacks. At the very least, it shows that Jason's psychic skill surpasses that of Charles. And if you argue that Charles was weakened by the struggle, then Charles' attack itself must also have been weakened.

Comment: "Cerebro amplified the telepathic power of the user, by strengthening their brainwaves. It also makes the users brain work extremely quickly by speeding up the neurons in the users brain." from the [wiki](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Cerebro_(Mutant_Detector))

Comment: @LiquidSame; Fair enough, but that is still not evidence to support the claim that Jason **must** be susceptible to Charles' attack. However, you have made me reevaluate this point, and a 4th option presents itself (Jason is not responsive in general, why would he respond to this?).

Comment: I didn't mean to say he must. Just the fact that he overpowered Charles before Cerebro doesn't mean he is stronger than him with the Cerebro and will block the attack. I really like your 4rth option. It would fit Striker to have his mutant weapon die with all the others after it's performed its task

Comment: @LiquidSame: Yes I like option 4 too. It fits better with Jason's story. If Jason cannot resist Cerebro's attack, then would Charles not simply have used Cerebro willingly and **then** fought back? Instead of sending the kill command, using Cerebro to defend against Jason?

Answer (score 1):

Flater's answer includes several excellent possibilities. Another possibility is that Jason's implication is to find "all mutants **'out there'**." It's like if a bad guy tells his accomplice to kill everyone, the bad guy obviously doesn't mean to *kill him too*.

Comment: True, but do consider that Jason is not the same Jason that Charles initially knew. This Jason is the experimental psychic weapon created by his own father (Striker). The fact that Striker would do this to his son shows that he does not care for his wellbeing. Assuming that Jason is commanded by his father (most likely against his wil but unable to fight back), there was probably no intention in that command for Jason to preserve himself. Arguably, the real Jason is already dead.

Comment: @Flater Interesting points!